# Find and Insert Only New Rows from Another Updated Sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, insert, vlookup

[image]

[image]

These two sheets are just samples I created to illustrate what I am trying to do.  I have a sheet that has about 700 rows of list data that have notes that also need to be kept.  Each month this sheet must be compared to the latest month's data which is kept in a second sheet in the same workbook.  This is done via VLOOKUPs contained in the first sheet.  Each month, new reports are run and exported to the 2nd sheet.

Every thing runs well except that VLOOKUPs do not account for NEW rows of data being added, which happens each month (usually 20 to 50 rows).  So the issue I have now is getting the main sheet to update with the new rows that have been added each month, then copy the VLOOKUPs again to do the comparisons.

I have been looking for a solution...VBA would be an option as well, I am thinking it would have to involve an array/tables but I am not strong in those.  I tried to use tables, named the ranges, but that only affected the VLOOKUP formulas...I need to actually get the new data (rows) pulled in.

The sheets are identical, sorted alphabetically/numerically by account number.  The only differences are the updated data associated with each account and, of course, any new rows.  Those rows are what I need to get added.

Comment: Anyone out there have any ideas?  I can get the table to update the VLOOKUPs but cannot get the main page updated with the new rows.  Thanks

Comment: Jeez, noone has any thoughts?  Is this impossible somehow?

Comment: Thank you for the edits.